# C1 True DBGrid 2 Checkbox Check/Uncheck with + key

Tags: c#, componentone

I'm using C1 True DBGrid 2. My grid has a checkbox column/field. I can use the space bar (alternate to a mouse click) to check and uncheck the box. I would like to program the + key on the num pad to do the same thing (for my ten-keyers). Nothing fancy...just when the checkbox has the focus.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Handle KeyDown event for TrueDBGrid and programmatically toggle value.